# Need To Read One Line At A Time From A .Csv File Using .Bat and assign tokens to vars

Tags: csv, batch-file, readline

I'm attempting to automate something at work that requires minimal background process. Normally I'd use C#, but this is problematic, as part of what I'm automating is a test process that scans the system looking for running processes. Command windows are fine, but most anything beyond that get's to be problematic.
As part of kicking off this series of tests, I am trying to find a way to get a batch file to read one line at a time from a .csv file. Each line contains 4 values (separated by commas, of course) which should be put into variables. The first var will be the test number. When starting the batch file, I'll be providing a test number as an arg, and want it to compare the test number received to the test number it read from the file. If it matches, continue testing. If not, move on to the next line and read that data into the variables.
Everything else is really simple, but I can't figure out how to get it to read and parse a .csv file one line at a time in the manner described. Any help would be appreciated.

Just for information, I am well aware of how to do this in C#, and I know there are many other solutions that would be better (easier) than batch files.  However, there are specific reasons why employing those solutions is a poor idea in our situation, so we're trying to go old school with the batch files.

Comment: [Processing a specific line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269395/how-to-set-a-variable-from-a-specific-line-number-in-a-text-file). [Parsing CSV files with batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470570/help-in-writing-a-batch-script-to-parse-csv-file-and-output-a-text-file)

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
rem Read theFile.csv and get 4 tokens separated by commas
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%a in (theFile.csv) do (
   rem Tokens read are placed in %%a, %%b, %%c and %%d replaceable parameters
   rem If first token is equal to first Batch file argument
   if %%a equ %1 (
      rem Continue testing here, ie
      echo %%a,%%b,%%c,%%d
   )
)
```